# Windbg conditional break point not working as expected, is my syntax correct?

Tags: c++, debugging, conditional-statements, windbg, break

I was trying to learn how to set conditional break point inside windbg, I've program named ConsoleApplication7 like below:

```
int main()
{
    int r1 = 0;
    r1 += 1;
    r1 = 3;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this program with VC. Then in windbg, I setup the "Symbol path" and "Source path", open ConsoleApplication7.exe inside windbg, windbg runs and opens the .cpp file.

Inside windbg I set a conditional break point, I wish the program should when in line "r1=3".

```
bp consoleapplication7!main "j (poi(r1)>2) ''; 'gc'"
```

But when I press "g", windbg doesn't say it "Hit breakpoint", but just print out registers information. After running "g" for 3 times, the program terminate, like below:

```
0:000> bp consoleapplication7!main "j (poi(r1)>2) ''; 'gc'"
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for ConsoleApplication7.exe
0:000> bl
 0 e 01251380     0001 (0001)  0:**** ConsoleApplication7!main "j (poi(r1)>2) ''; 'gc'"
0:000> g
eax=00718918 ebx=7efde000 ecx=0071b880 edx=00000001 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=01251380 esp=002afeb4 ebp=002aff00 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ConsoleApplication7!main:
01251380 55              push    ebp
0:000> g
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=77c02100 edi=77c020c0
eip=77b1fcd2 esp=002afe18 ebp=002afe34 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x12:
77b1fcd2 83c404          add     esp,4
0:000> g
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
```

Other commands like ba, bp works well in the program, just conditional break point doesn't.

### Is my conditional statement correct? Why it doesn't work?

I tried the suggestion from Dono's answer, but it shows another problem

```
0:000> bp ConsoleApplication7!main+0x3e "j (poi(r1) > 2) ''; 'gc'"
0:000> bl
 0 e 008e143e     0001 (0001)  0:**** ConsoleApplication7!main+0x3e "j (poi(r1) > 2) ''; 'gc'"
0:000> g
(4458.4840): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=00000000 ebx=7efde000 ecx=d3392f75 edx=00000001 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=cccccccc esp=0046f82c ebp=cccccccc iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
cccccccc ??              ???
```

Seems this conditional break point leads to an exception?
Thanks!

I also tried Blabb's suggestion, unluckily, it didn't work:

```
0:000> t "$$>a< c:\\autostep.txt"
Couldn't resolve error at 'r1) == 3 ) { dv } .else { t "$$>a< c:\\autostep.txt" } '
eax=00000001 ebx=7efde000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000001 esi=00000000 edi=001dfcb0
eip=013b13c0 esp=001dfbac ebp=001dfcb0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ConsoleApplication7!f:
013b13c0 55              push    ebp
```

Seems C++ style command didn't work, so I changed it to MASM style

```
j (poi(r1)==3)''; 't "$$>a< c:\\autostep.txt"'
```

Save as c:\autostep.txt
Then I restart windbg to reload it.

```
0:000> t "$$>a< c:\\autostep.txt"
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=bc260000 edx=0015dc38 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=77ba0e15 esp=0042f804 ebp=0042f830 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000244
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2d:
77ba0e15 8975fc          mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],esi ss:002b:0042f82c=00000000
0:000> g
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=77c02100 edi=77c020c0
eip=77b1fcd2 esp=0042fb94 ebp=0042fbb0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x12:
77b1fcd2 83c404          add     esp,4
```

This time, it has no syntax issue, when it doesn't break/stop as I expected. Did I miss anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command means: Unconditionally break at the start of the main function. Then, if r1 > 2, do nothing; otherwise, continue.

Note that bp takes an address and breaks on it. Because you have symbols (PDB), you are able to convert the symbol "consoleapplication7!main" into an address. This points to the start of the function, where r1 has not yet even been  initialized, so there is no way for it to be > 2, except for random garbage values.

So first you need to break at a more reasonable spot. There are multiple ways to do this. You can "unscramble" the assembly code `uf consoleapplication7!main` and determine the offset address to break. Something like `bp ConsoleApplication7!main+0x35 "j (poi(r1) > 2) ''; 'gc'"`. This may be a little difficult. An easier method is to specify the line number such as `` bp `driver.cpp:6` "j (poi(r1) > 2) ''; 'gc'" ``, assuming your main function is in a file called driver.cpp.

Also, you need to careful whether your application was compiled for debug or release mode. In release mode, most of your main function can be optimized away as the value of r1 can be pre-computed at compile time. This will naturally affect the offsets.

And finally, unless you have a habit of using j to mean "if", I would suggest the more modern `.if (condition) { commands } .else { commands }` syntax. While they do the same thing, the later is much more readable.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556853.aspx) for further details.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but windbg will say it encounters an exception. See above.

Comment: I have compiled the same program and the commands work here. Though with a +0x35 offset for me. How did you determine your offset? Did you try the line number version? Also, what version of WinDbg are you using? I notice that when I do bl, it shows the path to the cpp file and the line number. 0 e 012916a5 [c:\users\me\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\driver.cpp @ 6]    0001 (0001)  0:**** ConsoleApplication7!main+0x35 "j (poi(r1) > 2) ''; 'gc'"

Comment: You could try to debug your access violation. Check the call stack with k to see where it breaks.

Comment: Thinking about it more, this is probably due to the offset that you are using. It probably overwrote part of an instruction, resulting in unpredictable behavior. See here for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554613(v=vs.85).aspx   As I initially wrote, manually determining the offset is not that easy unless you are experienced with assembly. If in doubt, use the line numbers. You have the full, private symbols for this, so you should take advantage of this.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should be aware that your program will be optimized away to just `xor eax,eax ; ret`

Unless you compile in debug mode and explicitly disable optimizations with /Od switch

( I assume you are using visual monster project in debug mode which takes care of this )

Second you should be aware is that debugger does not know your r1 r2 or whatever unless symbol information is present and event then you should be aware that there are two expression evaluator MASM and C++ and by default windbg uses MASM

```
? poi(r1) == MASM evaluation 
?? r1 == c++ evaluation
```

other wise debugger understands only the variables that cpu understands  like     `BYTE , WORD , DWORD , QWORD .... etc` and addresses

when you set conditional breakpoint like bp xxxxxmodule!yyyyysymbol  "condition"  conditions are evaluated only on the address specified not further below 
so your condition was evaluated only on main

you should step further down and evaluate your condition on each step until you encounter a match

your code compiled and main() disassembled will look like this

```
0:000> .dml_flow steptest!main .
                              <No previous node>                    


          STEPTEST!main (013e6aa0):
          e:\test\steptest\steptest.cpp
          2     013e6aa0 push    ebp                                
          2     013e6aa1 mov     ebp,esp                            
          2     013e6aa3 push    ecx                                
          3     013e6aa4 mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],0                
          4     013e6aab mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]              
          4     013e6aae add     eax,1                              
          4     013e6ab1 mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],eax              
          5     013e6ab4 mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],3                
          6     013e6abb xor     eax,eax                            
          7     013e6abd mov     esp,ebp                            
          7     013e6abf pop     ebp                                
          7     013e6ac0 ret                                        


                                <No next node>                      
0:000> lsa .
     1: int main()
     2: {
     3:     int r1 = 0;
>    4:     r1 += 1;
     5:     r1 = 3;
     6:     return 0;
     7: }
```

so your condition can be true only on line 6 or in assembly  at address `013e6abb xor eax, eax`

you set a `conditional bp on  013e6aa0` and the condition was evaluated at that address only

you need to find a way to step till  013e6abb

that is you should

```
step <evaluate> if match stop else repeat step and evaluate until match occurs
```

to do that put the following line in a file named autostep.txt and save it to c:\

explanation of the script

if the c++ expression r1 equals 3 show the locals else step and reevaluate by running this script again ( so this script will be executed on each instruction sequence until a match is found )

```
.if ( @@c++(r1) == 3 ) { dv } .else { t "$$>a< c:\\autostep.txt" }
```

now open the exe in windbg and do

```
bp xxxxmod!main
g
t "$$>a< c:\\autostep.txt"
```

windbg will break when r1 is 3

```
E:\test\STEPTEST>cdb -c "g steptest!main" STEPTEST.exe

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'g steptest!main'

STEPTEST!main:
013e6aa0 55              push    ebp
0:000> t "$$>a< c:\\autostep.txt"
             r1 = 0n3

013e6abb 33c0            xor     eax,eax
0:000> ?? r1
int 0n3
0:000> ? poi(r1)
Evaluate expression: 3 = 00000003
0:000> ? &main ; ? &@eip
Evaluate expression: 20867744 = 013e6aa0
Evaluate expression: 20867771 = 013e6abb
0:000>
```

you can invoke the script in cmd.exe

```
cat c:\autostep.txt
.if ( @@c++(r1) == 3 ) { dv } .else { t "$$>a< c:\\autostep.txt" }

cdb -c "g steptest!main;$$>a< c:\autostep.txt"  STEPTEST.exe

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'g steptest!main;$$>a< c:\autostep.txt'

             r1 = 0n3

eax=00000001 ebx=7ffd6000 ecx=a4894de4 edx=00000001 esi=00a2dd04 edi=00a2dd08
eip=009d6abb esp=0019f8d0 ebp=0019f8d4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
STEPTEST!main+0x1b:
009d6abb 33c0            xor     eax,eax
0:000>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, seems doesn't work, see update above

Comment: bp main ;g when bp hits do t  "$$>a< c:\autostep.txt"  for the script to resolve r1 it needs to be in scope r1 is not global and is not visible when you are in ntdll and simply hitting g isnt going to produce any magic